# Тире в сложносочиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь тире перед "это"?

Продукция, представленная на выставке, включала в себя трубопроводную арматуру для нефтегазового сектора, это шаровые краны 11с67п СФ, 11с67пСУФ, 11с67п 8РП, 11с67п 5СФ, 11с67п 2ЦФ, 10нж45фт ЦФ, а также арматура с пневмоприводом.

Answer (score 1):

В том виде, в котором есть, это бессоюзное сложное предложение(это-подлежащее). Если поставили запятую, тире будет лишним.

Я бы поставила двоеточие и превратила в простое с однородными членами и обобщающим словом: Продукция, представленная на выставке, включала в себя трубопроводную арматуру для нефтегазового сектора: шаровые краны 11с67п СФ, 11с67пСУФ, 11с67п 8РП, 11с67п 5СФ, 11с67п 2ЦФ, 10нж45фт ЦФ, а также арматуру с пневмоприводом.

Comment: Людмила, я не уверен, что "арматура с пневприводом" относится к предыдущему списку (трубопроводная, для нефтегазового сектора). А у вас - попадает однозначно.

Comment: "(это-подлежащее)"??? ===  А по-моему -- **частица**, абсолютно лишняя в исходном предложении.

Comment: Нет, не попадает. Если Вы о том, что после однородных членов нужно тире, чтобы отделить от продолжения предложения, то тире здесь не нужно, т.к. по условиям контекста дальше идёт противительный союз, перед ним необходима запятая.

Comment: Да, это  в данном случае  подлежащее, а не частица

Comment: Мне кажется, оба варианта имеют право на существование. Предложение с двоеточием становится проще и яснее, но и со вставной конструкцией оно смотрится неплохо, и это, наверное, ближе к тому, что хотел сказать автор.

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно ли здесь тире перед "это"?

НУЖНО (вместо запятой!).

Но лучше слово ***это*** выкинуть, предложение перестроить.

**P.S.**

А предложение в вопросе (*"Продукция, представленная на выставке, включала в себя..."*) -- не сложносочинённое. Простое.

Answer (score 0):

Так как однородные члены предложения, следующие за обобщающим словом АРМАТУРУ, имеют характер уточнения, обособленного приложения, перед ними можно поставить ТИРЕ, а не двоеточие. Частицу ЭТО действительно лучше опустить.

Выражение АРМАТУРА С ПНЕВМОПРИВОДОМ  необходимо поставить в нужную форму:                                 **..., а также арматурУ с пневмоприводом.** Перед противительным союзом А тире ОПУСКАЕТСЯ, так как запятая его поглощает:

***Продукция, представленная на выставке, включала в себя трубопроводную арматуру для нефтегазового сектора -  шаровые краны 11с67п СФ, 11с67пСУФ, 11с67п 8РП, 11с67п 5СФ, 11с67п 2ЦФ, 10нж45фт ЦФ, а также арматурУ с пневмоприводом.***

*Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а тире или ставится, или опускается (есть пример, когда ставится; см.ссылку - Е.К.).  **Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки (Г.) — запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.***[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103)

**Если же частицу ЭТО не убирать**, то получается  другая история.Тогда весь ряд однородных членов вместе с ЭТО  превращается во вставное предложение и оформляются однородные члены в именительном падеже. (Ср.: *Всех девочек -  это Таня, Катя, Наташа и Инна - объединяло желание научиться танцевать.*)  Тире ставится и в этом случае. А вот выражение *арматура с пневмоприводом* останется в именительном, если входит во вставную конструкцию, и в винителном, если не входит.